# Comparing first and last element of list with append

Tags: prolog, append

I'm a bit of a prolog noob thats why i am asking here, i couldn't find the anser else where.

The thing i am trying to do is this function in a different way:

```
firstlast([H,H]).
firstlast([F,_|T]):- firstlast([F|T]).
```

it basicly finds out if the first and last element is the same in a list with two or more elements.

Now i want to make this function with append, so instead of recursion just a single call to append.

```
append([],U,U).
append([H|T],U,[H|V]) :- append(T,U,V).
```

Example of how it should work:

```
firslasta([1,2,3,4,1]).
true.

firstlasta([1,3,4,1,5]).
false-

firstlasta([2,5,2,3,6,2]).
true.
```

Any help with this would be greatly appriciated :).

Comment: append takes three lists. `append(A, B, A+B)`. You never assinged the middle list.

Comment: It's worth noting that `append/3` itself is accomplished through recursion, so I don't think you'll be saving any computing power by using it.  Your first answer seems more elegant to me.

Answer (score 2):

it's easy, using idiomatic Prolog:

to identify the first element of a list, (the Head, you know), we use[Head|_], where the underscore, an anonymous var, stay for an unspecified (the uninteresting) list' tail.

In a list of length 1, we have just the last to identify. Then append a list starting with an Elem to a list of 1 Elem:

```
firstlast(L) :- append([Elem|_], [Elem], L).
```